# Obtain MAX of column and display for each row

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm trying to obtain the MAX of a particular column in a Power BI Report and place this as a new Measure within each ROW of the same dataset. Please see the example below.

[image: Excel Sample]

Is this possible in DAX and via DirectQuery/LiveConnection? The report is pointing to a tabular model but due to outside factors the measure must be created in the report.

Thanks

Comment: What have you researched / tried so far?

Comment: Since you are using an aggregated value have you thought of using a measure instead of a calculated column?

Comment: Thanks M D, but Calculated Columns aren't possible with LiveConnection to Tabular Models, hence the measure route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this a few ways.  Essentially, you need override the filter context so that the MAX function isn't just running over whatever slice you're showing in the visual.  Using CALCULATE or the iterator function MAXX, set the wrap the table in the ALL() function to override the context and calculate max over all rows.

```
= CALCULATE(MAX([Calendar`Year]), ALL('Smithfield_Fiscal_Calendar'))
```

or

```
= MAXX(ALL('Smithfield_Fiscal_Calendar'), [Calendar`Year])
```

---

To get the breakout by date, you'll need to include a Date table in your model.  PowerBI makes this possible with a few different DAX options.  As an example, go to your Model tab, click 'New Table' and put in the following expression:

```
MyCalendar = CALENDAR(DATE(2019,1,1), DATE (2019,1,10))
```

This is a little trivial -- you'd want to use a useful range of dates but this one matches your example above.  Next, add a column to [MyCalendar]

```
CalendarMonthYear = month([date]) & "-" & year([date])
```

Go to your budget table and add a similar field

```
BudgetMonthYear = month([date]) & "-" & year([date])
```

Go into your Model view and create a relationship between CalendarMonthYear and BudgetMonthYear.  This will associate every date in the date table with the particular budget row from your budget table.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Ryan, but this only produces the value for the date in which the budget exists and not each day.

For example we receive the Budget on the 2nd day of each month, and I would need to see this replicated on each row for each day in that month.

Comment: Ok, you are going to need a date table.  This is a pretty standard element in BI solutions and there's lots about them online.  This basically is a new table that lists out a row for every day of the calendar, and lots of other traits.  You'll need to add a field to your budget table that is just the month and year, and join that to the month/year on the date table.  This will associate the one budget row with all dates in the date table in that month.  It takes a little doing, but it's not too bad and probably something you will do a lot.